# Need to join values with comma of closest TDs after they're checked

Tags: jquery

I have a working script right now that gets the value of the closest TD element inside a checkbox, and then passes the value to the URL.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input:checkbox").change(function(index){  
  var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.views-field-nid').text();

$("#compare[type='button']").click(function() {
window.location = 'URL/'+value+'';
 });
});
```

My current problem right now is finding a way to join these values, separated by a comma.

I've looked up map/join, but when I tested it, it didn't work.

Anyone know of any solutions?

Comment: I would avoid having a click event inside a change event.

Comment: Also please include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `map()`, that's exactly what you'd need in order to best achieve this. You can use it to build an array of all the selected values before using `join()` to combine them.

Also note that you should avoid nesting your event handlers. You can achieve that by separating the `change` and `click` event logic and using setting a `data` attribute which can be read by the button as needed.  Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $btn = $("#compare[type='button']");
  let $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");

  $checkboxes.on('change', e => {
    let value = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get().join(',');
    $btn.data('value', value);
  }).trigger('change');
  
  $btn.on('click', e => {
    var url = `URL/${$(e.target).data('value')}`;
    console.log(url); // for demo only
    // window.location.assign(url); // uncomment this in your local version
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" value="5" checked /><br />
<button id="compare" type="button">Compare</button>
```